# Migrating data from heroku

Tags: migration, heroku, datamapper

I have a heroku app running in production. 
I'd like to "clone" it to make a dev version, which I can modify without affecting current users. So far I did not find a simple way to dump the db (schema+data) and pump it back to the dev version. 
Heroku suggests taps but I'd like (if possible) to avoid recreating foreign keys.
Then there is a the [pgbackups](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-migrate) way but I'd really prefer to avoid loading potentially sensible db data from a temporary url.
I was wondering, I am using datamapper os ORM. 
Can I use that to dump the db (maybe on a local file) and restore (schema+data) to another application's db?

Comment: Nevermind. I have found the solution here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#transfers

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a problem with `heroku db:pull` and `heroku db:push` - foreign keys come down as it.

Comment: Yep, but with transfer you move stuff from one db to another server-side, you don't download to upload again. Anyway, happy there are many ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Maybe I was too fast. Yesterday I tried that and it worked perfectly. Today it doesn't. can't resolve db url is the message. But the url exists, for sure. And heroku support does not reply.